# Run a module locally

Tags: ansible

I'm developing a smoke test playbook which simply goes through and ensures that I get a HTTP 200 out of all of our servers.

I was originally doing this:

```
---
- hosts: prod
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: smoke test
        uri: url=http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/ status_code=200
```

The problem here is that these servers apparently don't have httplib2 installed on them, so the URI command fails.

Is there a way for me to run the uri module on my local machine to the remote machines to just run through all of them and curl each one? I'd like to use a module if possible, because it's easier to check that the return code is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can delegate any task to localhost or another remote host with `delegate_to`:

```
- name: smoke test
  uri: url=http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/ status_code=200
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Also, there is the `local_action` module, but I prefer the `delegate_to` way.

```
- name: smoke test
  local_action: uri url=http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/ status_code=200
```

Comment: `delegate_to` also feels more intuitive because `local_action` requires you to use the shorthand syntax (`module var=value var2=value`), whereas you're free to use YAML object syntax if you delegate the task.

Comment: Would that mean that the command is fully executed locally ? Let's say you have something like this:
```
    local_action: command which nginx
    register: check_nginx
```
Then you have another block looking for nginx's existence with something like that:
```
    - fail: msg="nginx unavailable"
      when: nginx_check.rc == 1
```
Does that mean that playbook will fail in case nginx is not installed locally or will it fail if is not installed remotely ?

Comment: @NickoGlayre Vars by default are registered for `inventory_hostname`, not for the host the task was delegated to. Depending on what you want to do, you can change that, see [delegated facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts)

Comment: @geerlingguy no, it doesn't force the shorthand syntax onto you. You can start a YAML mapping with `local_action:`, specify the module to run with `module: foobar` as property to the mapping and any other parameters the module needs as further properties. However, I'm still torn between `delegate_to` and `local_action`. The lack of a target to specify for the latter may be an advantage, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: i think there is a subtle difference between delegate_to and local_action.  with delegate_to an ssh connection is made to that host whereas a local_action does not require that host to run sshd (assuming you are delegating to localhost). i could be wrong, but it feels that way.

Comment: @Greg I was wondering about this as well. From the reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks

"It may be useful to use a playbook locally, rather than by connecting over SSH." Which implies that `connection: local` should be used to avoid using SSH.

Comment: since i posted this i have done a lot of ansible playbooks :-)  i have shifted entirely to local_action because of the speed and lack of operational complexity (you don't have to be able to ssh localhost).  the syntax is different, which is a drawback.  but if the entire play is to be delegated to localhost you can use connection:local in which case the syntax for the entire play can use regular task syntax.

Comment: You can just add a file `localhost` in your `hostvars` dir and set the connection to local and no ssh connection is required.